# How can I add raw HTML/JavaScript to a Dash application?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I'd like to have a tacky Matrix-style background in my Dash application. How can I add code for that, for example, what you'd find [here](https://code.sololearn.com/Wj7ZWBg5m2OG/#html)?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very high level question with a lot of things to work out.

First I would suggest you read [this documentation page](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources) on how you are able to add the necessary javascript and css to your page and modifying the underlying template for your Dash app to add the required canvas. Then you should be able to combine the matrix background code example with your app.

You definitely will need good knowledge in HTML, JS and CSS to put all pieces together.